# how to counting data from each column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, pivot-table

i have some mysql script for pivot table and then counting some data inside that:

```
SELECT A.Line,
       week1.1stweek, week2.2ndweek,
       IFNULL(week1.1stweek,0) + IFNULL(week2.2ndweek,0) AS TOTAL
FROM inspection_report AS A
LEFT JOIN(
           SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 1stweek
           FROM inspection_report
           WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
           GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
          ) AS week1 USING (Line)
LEFT JOIN(
           SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 2ndweek
           FROM inspection_report
           WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14
           GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
          ) AS week2 USING (Line)
GROUP BY Line
```

it makes the table head show like button.
after that i want to make a "SUM" below each column like:

```
Line          1stweek            2ndweek             total
1               12                 2                   14
2               3                  0                    3
SUM             15                 2                   17
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

You'd have to modify the outer select statement though to

```
SELECT A.Line,
       sum(week1.1stweek) as 1stweek, sum(week2.2ndweek) 2ndweek,
       sum(IFNULL(week1.1stweek,0) + IFNULL(week2.2ndweek,0)) AS TOTAL
```

for the modifier to take effect. Change `A.Line` to `IFNULL(A.Line, "SUM") as Line` instead if you need it to be labelled as such.

Comment: but it not counting all.it just show the last data from each column.

Comment: after use IFNULL(A.Line, "SUM") as Line the "SUM" not show at below still "null".why it happens?

Comment: Can you post what your sql statement looks like now?

Comment: i post my db structure so you can try.

Comment: i have found the answer.before i use GROUP BY Line WITH ROLL UP. and after i use IFNULL(A.Line, "SUM") as Line and dont forget to use GROUP BY A.Line WITH ROLLUP.

Answer (score 0):

This interested me, so I implemented a equivalent in an online SQL sandbox, [here](http://headfirstlabs.com/sql_hands_on/).

`select ifnull(toy, "SUM") as toy, sum(s1.store1) as store2, sum(s2.store2) as store1, sum(ifnull(store1,0)+ifnull(store2,0)) as total from (select toy_id, sum(inventory) as store1 from store_inventory where store_id=1 group by toy_id) as s1 left join (select toy_id, sum(inventory) as store2 from store_inventory where store_id=2 group by toy_id) as s2 using (toy_id) left join toy_info using (toy_id) group by toy with rollup;`

(Pardon my lack of markdown skills, this is my first post.)